# execute method when iPhone enters landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, events, delegates

Is there a delegate that will get called when the iPhone enters landscape or portrait mode? I need to change the style and place objects in a different place when the iPhone get's rotated. Do I have to do this with the accelerometer?  Moreover if there exist such a delegate do I have to create the connection in interface builder. I am new to objective-c...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register to listen for the orientation change notification.

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    //Tell it to start monitoring the accelerometer for orientation             
[device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    //Get the notification centre for the app   
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];    
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:device];
```

Implement `orientationChanged:` method, which will be called when the device change the orientation. you could put code to check the orientation type and called your method.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"Orientation  has changed: %d", [[note object] orientation]);
}
```

Remove notification in `dealloc`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Check the blog post

[Reacting to iPhone's orientation](http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2009/6/26/reacting-to-iphones-orientation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Implement didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation in your view controller

> -(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 8, with the message "Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: to make interface-based adjustments."

Answer (score 0):

You can get UIDevice to generate notifications for orientation events. See the [documentation for UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

If you need to detect the change at any moment, you might consider calling `-beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` in your app's delegate.

Also, if you are using `UIViewController`s, there are

- `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`
- `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: duration:`
- `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`