# How to get the screen size when device rotated?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get screen size and get like following.

```
CGRect deviceSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

But when device is rotated (from upside to left), deviceSize's size value is not changed.

How to get changed screen size when rotated?

Is there a supported API or make manually?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628273/execute-method-when-iphone-enters-landscape-mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686882/incorrect-frame-window-size-after-re-orientation-in-iphone might be helpful to you...

Comment: Thanks Jim.  It is what I have wanted. :D